# restrict maven to not download all poms

Tags: maven, pom.xml

Please look at this pom.xm 's snippet. We use this to pull latest artifact for this specific dependency. The problem is with this approach, it pulls all older versions pom too for the entire range `[1.1.0-100,1.2.0-999)`. Since we use this range for pulling others jars too, we don't want to change this. Is there a way to restrict maven to not download all poms for entire range not slowing down build process ?

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-  4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>rest.lib</groupId>
<artifactId>rest-lib</artifactId>
<version>${LIB.VERSION}</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>rest-lib</name>
<description>REST specific libraries.</description>
<properties>
      <JAR.VERSION>[1.1.0-100,1.2.0-999)</JAR.VERSION>
      </properties>
       <dependency>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <groupId>com.myartifacts.rest</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-schema</artifactId>
        <version>${JAR.VERSION}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>*</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I would never use version ranges. Can you elaborate a little bit more cause i really don't understand the purpose of this?

Comment: Well.. first off sorry for late response. Got caught up. Requirement is - if I have a dependency on some jar and if that jar changes all the time (due to checkins and deploy) then I would like to refer to latest jars deployed in latest build. We deal with that using versions. Question was to look for better way to restrict jar versions (one option is I can restrict the range) but i thought there may be a better approach to deal with this.

Comment: if the question makes sense {It's a practical problem on project and not theoritical] please upvote the question... I need to bump my reputation to interact/collaborate more on forums. reputation < 50 has very few privileges.

Comment: Also have this problem - the only solution right now is to update Maven source. If you look here https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/master/maven-resolver-provider/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/repository/internal/DefaultVersionRangeResolver.java you will see that this step goes and brings back all the versions... the usage though during model resolution (https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/2a23d7bf16612ff1868941669bde3a7d323a93e2/maven-resolver-provider/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/repository/internal/DefaultModelResolver.java) only takes the highest version from those results.